# Why can't I use the FunctionComponent to get the children's passes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I want to create a button for ui ki, but I have a problem with FC
error: The "children" property does not exist in the "MyButtonProps" type.
Maybe I need to define a type for my functional component? If so, how do I do it?

It was expected to get this

Comment: import React, { FC} from 'react';

export interface MyButtonProps {
    color: string;
    big: boolean;
}

const MyButton: FC<MyButtonProps> = ({children, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <button {...props} style={{color}}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

export default MyButton;

Answer (score 0):

you need to define type for your functional component props ('MyButtonProps') and make sure it includes children property

Comment: Please add code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript we need to explicitly define the props type, since you might have missed what has caused the problem. Two ways you can have this resolved is either to have type defined as below:

```
import React from 'react';

// Define the type for your component props
type MyComponentProps = {
  // Define the props here
}

// Define your functional component using React.FC
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = (props) => {
  // Component implementation
}

export default MyComponent;
```

OR

```
import React from 'react';

// Define the type for your button props directly within the function parameters
const MyButton = ({ children, onClick }: { children: React.ReactNode; onClick?: () => void }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      {children} {/* Render the children */}
    </button>
  );
};

export default MyButton;
```

In the second method, object destructuring defines the props type directly within the function parameters.

Comment: Thanks, helped me.                            children: React.ReactNode